# iPhone - MFMailComposeViewController delegate incompatible type

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, messageui

I have a view controller which opens an MFMailComposeViewController modally. When I try to set the mail view controller's delegate to the parent view controller, I get this warning:

```
Assigning to 'id<UINavigationControllerDelegate>' from incompatible
type 'MoreViewController *__strong'
```

The parent view controller definitely has MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate in its interface declaration and is implementing the delegate method `-mailComposeController: didFinishWithResult:error:` as follows:

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Delegate called");
}
```

I really don't understand why the parent view controller is being recognized as a UINavigationControllerDelegate, as I don't implement those methods nor do I declare it as such. I wouldn't be so worried about it but the delegate method never gets called, so I'm guessing this "mismatch" is part of the problem.

If it helps, this is how I am initting the mail view controller, in `viewDidLoad`:

```
// MAIL
self.mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
self.mail.delegate = self;
```

Thanks in advance for any thoughts you may have.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You want to set `mailComposeDelegate` rather than `delegate`:

```
self.mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;
```

Basically, you were setting the `delegate` which because `MFMailComposeViewController` inherits from `UINavigationController`, means that `delegate` needs to implement `UINavigationControllerDelegate`.

Comment: No probs. That's a mistake I've made many many times and still do to this day when I'm a bit sleepy! You're not alone :-).